# Rails index.html.erb do not show image.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm actually use `<img src="/image.png">` and this do not show image. Just #brokenimage. How can i fix it (**image storage is /views/projects/**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the rails asset pipeline to deliver images.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Or you can place it in your public folder. (`public/image.png`)